# Custom AngularJS directive including a dash in the name doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've written the following Angular directive that will add the "required" attribute to all children:

```
.directive("requireall", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', //only want it triggered for attributes
    compile: function(element, scope) {
      // Prevent infinite loop on compile
      element.removeAttr("requireall");

      var allChildren = element.find('*');
      allChildren.attr('required', 'required');
      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

I really want to call it "require-all" but if I rename it then it doesn't work anymore. Why is "requireall" working but not "require-all"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Angular converts camelCasing to snake-casing, so your requireall directive needs to be renamed to `requireAll`, then you can use `require-all` in your markup (or `data-require-all` if you want to correctly markup custom tags). Confused me for a while at first.

Comment: It's actually [kebab-case, list-case or even spinal-case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). Snake-case would result in `require_all`

Comment: @Plantface I've seen it referred to as snake case on the Angular docs, although I can see that Wikipedia proves me wrong again ;-)

Comment: Arrrgh, thanks. Had this problem before but forgot about it. Not intuitive behaviour in my opinion!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Rename the directive to "requireAll";

```
.directive("requireAll",…)
```

And a directive named `abcDef` can be used as `abc-def` in the markup.

Comment: You should clarify that requireAll can be used as 'require-all' in the markup