# Angular1 Send Variable to directive

Tags: angularjs, variables, directive

How can I send variable to directive? My code actually doesn't work, but I did everything from your comments :(
As you can see in my `.html` file, `{{ ctrl.emptyParent.name }}` is working.

**.html**

```
<div cms-dropdown emptyParent="emptyParent.name" classes="btn-default">
    <i style="opacity: 0.8">{{ emptyParent.name }}</i>
</div>
```

**directive**

```
.directive('cmsDropdown', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            emptyParent: '=',
        },
        transclude: true,
        template:
            `
            {{emptyParent}} Hi

            `
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){

        }
    };
}]);
```

**and variable**

```
this.emptyParent = {
    _id: 'empty',
    name: '~~#(brak)#~~',
    parentAlbumId: null,
    position: -1,
    createdDate: undefined,
    modifiedDate: undefined
};
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432198/passing-variable-to-angular-directive

Comment: `<cms-directive>` not `<div cms-directive>`

Comment: @Smit <div cms-directive> works just fine if the author would like the directive to load in a div

Comment: @Smit this directive is attribute not an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `emptyParent="emptyParent.name"` to `empty-parent="emptyParent.name"`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.emptyParent = {"name":"jhon"}
})
.directive('cmsDropdown', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            emptyParent: '=',
        },
        transclude: true,
        template:
            `
            {{emptyParent}} Hi
              
            `,
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs){

        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div cms-dropdown empty-parent="emptyParent.name" classes="btn-default">
    <i style="opacity: 0.8">{{ emptyParent.name }}</i>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Why is it working and mine isn't?

Comment: could you explain, why did you ask to change X to Y?

Comment: i mean you wrote change emptyParent to empty-parent, I will like know why?

Comment: @zgrybus need to change `emptyParent` to `empty-parent` and there was a comma missing between link function and template

Comment: Yes i noticed that, but it's forced by angular, that we need to use comma?

Comment: @Smit check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807763/custom-angular-directive-including-a-dash-in-the-name-doesnt-work?answertab=active#tab-top. This will also apply to the directive scope variable

Comment: @zgrybus when you are adding new property to object need to separate from comma