# Undefined value in ng-model. Error: Expression 'undefined' in attribute ... non-assignable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a page called index.html and I embedded a component called add-circle-form in the page. 
 What I want to do:

I want to save the user choices in add-circle-form.js and pass the data to index.js, when the user clicked on the option list on add-circle-form.html. However, I got an error when I clicked on the dropdown list:

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute    'selectedCircles' used with directive 'addCircleForm' is non-assignable!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=selectedCircles&p2=addCampaignForm
at angular.js:68
at parentSet (angular.js:10216)
at parentValueWatch (angular.js:10229)
at regularInterceptedExpression (angular.js:16355)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17828)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18102)
at HTMLElement.s (angular-material.min.js:11)
at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3546)
at HTMLElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3534)
```

Below is my code:

index.html

```
<add-campaign-form
on-submit="submit()"
selectedCircles="selectedCircles"></add-campaign-form>
```

index.js (controller of index.html) where
I defined the object *selectedCircles* here:

```
function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedCircles = {};
}
```

add-circle-form.html (component)

```
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Target Circles</label>
    <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.selectedCircles"
               md-on-close="clearSearchTerm()"
               multiple>
      <md-select-header>
        <input ng-model="searchTerm"
               type="search"
               placeholder="Search for a circle.."
               class="target-circles-header-searchbox md-text">
      </md-select-header>
      <md-optgroup label="circles">
        <md-option ng-value="circle" ng-repeat="circle in circles |
          filter:searchTerm">{{circle}}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
```

add-circle-form.js (controller of add-circle-form.html)

```
    $scope.circles = ['Circle A', 'Circle B', 'Circle C', 'Circle D'];
    $scope.searchTerm;
    $scope.clearSearchTerm = function() {
        $scope.searchTerm = '';
    };
    $element.find('input').on('keydown', function(ev){
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
```

bindings in add-circle-form.js

```
    bindings: {
        onSubmit: '&',
        selectedCircles: '='
    }
```

I think the problem is that I am using ng-model="$ctrl.selectedCircles" but I have no idea why I cannot assign value to $ctrl.selectedCircles as I've already defined it and two-way bound it. Could you suggest me a way on how to pass the data to index.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `selectedCircles` to `selected-circles` in index.html

```
<add-campaign-form
on-submit="submit()"
selected-circles="selectedCircles"></add-campaign-form>
```

Comment: Yes it works for me now, may I know how does this solution work? I mean why I cannot put selectedCircles there?

Comment: @nanopotato check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807763/custom-angular-directive-including-a-dash-in-the-name-doesnt-work?answertab=active#tab-top